# Are cartography questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A common thing to do when building a world is to build a *map* of that world. This typically outlines the various countries, important landmarks, factions, terrain, climate, etc. of the world.

I present a list of various cartography related questions. Respond with thoughts on whether they are on topic or not. Some of them may be considered to be only tangentially related to worldbuilding. The hope here is to create a line in the sand, as a community, as to what cartography questions are allowed and what are not.

- What factors could result in inaccurate mapping of a world?
- How can I develop a naming scheme for cities and towns in my world?
- What are some ways mass terraforming in a short period of time could occur?
- How can the shape of borders develop within a continent?
- How quickly could erosion cause an island to break off from a continent?
- What are some tools to create maps of my world?
- How can I draw biome variations on a medium scale regional map?
- How do I mark a desert in a map?
- Advice on making a decent looking city / large town

Comment: I recommend using the `[on-topic]` tag for this question.

Answer (score 13):

I would say yes. A map is the world, so it's basically world building at it's core. And even if Cartography.SE did exist, it might not accept questions that don't have a realistic core (some of the questions you've added I imagine would be off topic). So people could come here.

Some of the questions above I wouldn't consider cartography (particularly "Advice on making a decent looking city / large town"), but would still be on-topic.

Comment: Maybe I see this from an incorrect point of view, but as for me, the only question of given example pool, that fits here and is on main scope of this site, is: "_What are some ways mass terraforming in a short period of time could occur_".

Answer (score 7):

General cartography questions are probably better suited to GIS.SE.  Cartography questions that involve fantasy elements and similar hypothetical elements or are otherwise not things that real world cartographers deal with would make sense to cover here.